# Is there a way to rename the built in speaker name? (Mac Mini M1)

Tags: mac-mini, speakers, apple-silicon

I am trying to rename the default or built-in speaker name on the Mac mini. Currently, it is "Mac mini Speakers". I want to be able to change or rename it.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename the existing audio output, but you can create another one with your chosen name.

Use **Audio MIDI Setup.app** (in the Utilities folder) to create an Aggregate Device that only contains your mini's speakers. (Normally, this is used to create a single input/output for multiple devices.)

Click on the + button at the bottom of the window to create a new Aggregate device, and then double-click on the item in the sidebar to rename it.

You will need to tick the "Use" checkbox next to "Mac mini Speakers".

[image]

You can then choose a more descriptive name, in preference to "Mac Mini Speakers".

This will be listed in System Preferences, in addition to the built-in audio output names. (However, it seems that the menulet doesn't get updated immediately. You'll need to log in again.)

Comment: Is there a way to change it in the files like .plist or something?

Comment: Well, obviously, there's a text string somewhere where the name is defined. But it's not in a user-accessible file (i.e. it's in the read-only System volume), and Apple provides no method for changing it. Why is the default name not what you want?

Comment: Because I have names like “USB audio CODEC” that I want to change to “CalDigit IN” and CalDigit OUT” to make more sense. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekxi9.jpg