# How to rename USB devices

Tags: audio, usb, macos

I have two microphones that I connect to my machine over 3.5mm AUX to USB-C dongles. Both of them are literally named "USB-C to 3.5mm Headphone Jack Adapter" (made by Apple) and it becomes very confusing to differentiate the two in OBS. I know it's possible to rename USB flash drives easily, but what about two dongles?

Can I do this on the command line?

Comment: Can you go to System Information -> USB -> USB-C to 3.5mm Headphone Jack Adapter and check if the Product ID and Vendor ID are both identical? If they aren't, the only workaround I'm aware of is to create an aggregate device for each adapter; if not, there's a workaround you can do involving a custom kext.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename a USB device but you can probably use [this trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421154/506284) to help recognize the inputs in OBS:

Use Audio MIDI Setup.app (in the Utilities folder) to create an Aggregate Device that only contains your mini's speakers. (Normally, this is used to create a single input/output for multiple devices.)

Click on the + button at the bottom of the window to create a new Aggregate device, and then double-click on the item in the sidebar to rename it.

You will need to tick the "Use" checkbox next to "Mac mini Speakers".

[image]

You can then choose a more descriptive name, in preference to "Mac Mini Speakers".